# Rich Faces 4.0 With jsf2.0

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am making web app using JSF 2.0 and Rich Faces 4.0
I want to know what should be minimum- entry in Web.xml and faces config.xml so that application will run successfully . Is order of servlet declaration  matters , I am saying because when i am running my app with custom security filter, rich faces component is not rendering sometime . Can you please give me example Web.xml file.

---

EDIT:

**Thanks BalusC **

Problem is when i am adding security filter Rich faces component is not rendered ??   I am sensing you my web.xml entry and security filter. can you please tell me what is wrong i am doing here

```
</p><p> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>MyApp</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>classic</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.my.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>`   </p><p> Security Filter </p>  <p>  `import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ils.core.util.IlsUtil;

/**
 * @author --FILTER implementing class; Checks the authentication of every
 *         request
 */
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("--------SecurityFilter.doFilter()--------");
    boolean redirToLoginPage = false;
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    InputParamDto parameter = null;
    Object user = null;
    try {
        parameter = (InputParamDto) httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute(
                "inputParameter");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (parameter == null || IlsUtil.ifEmpty(parameter.getConsumer_id())) {
        redirToLoginPage = true;
    }
    if (httpRequest.getRequestURI().indexOf("login") == -1
            && redirToLoginPage) {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        httpResponse.setContentType("text/plain");
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        String redirTo = httpRequest.getScheme() + "://"
                + httpRequest.getServerName() + ":"
                + httpRequest.getServerPort()
                + httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/";
        httpResponse.setHeader("Location", redirTo);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, resp);
    }

}

public void destroy() {
}
}`</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in my project so I solved it by adding the path in the validation where the richfaces resources and jsf are being loaded.

Something like this:

```
String uri = hr.getRequestURI();            
if (uri.endsWith(".view")
                && !uri.contains(ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)
                && !uri.contains(ResourceHandlerImpl.RICHFACES_RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {
            //You put your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the usual `FacesServlet` mapping in `web.xml` is enough for JSF 2.0. The `faces-config.xml` can be left empty. RichFaces 4.0 doesn't require additional configuration in either file.

---

**Update** as per your update: you need to map your security filter on a different URL pattern. RichFaces will dynamically include CSS/JS files on the same mapping of the FacesServlet. However, your security filter is apparently blocking those requests (didn't you pay attention to those lot of system out prints in the log?). I'd suggest to put secured files in a folder and map the filter on there instead, e.g. `/secured/*`, `/private/*`, `/app/*`, etc.

Unrelated to the problem, you've got there *a lot* of `FacesServlet` mappings. Please keep it clean and stick to one. I'd personally recommend `*.xhtml`. This way the endusers won't be able to view the raw JSF source anymore by just editing the URL in browser address bar.